# Why the mongodb update method creates a new collection with the extension '_keys'?

Tags: python, mongodb-update

I used the mongoDB method update to modify existing documents in a collection named `annotations`. My command, written in a Python script, is:

```
db['annotations'].update({'_id': annotation['_id']}, {'$set': {'orthologs': orthologs}}, False)
```

The field `orthologs` must be modify to contain a new subfield `UniProt` that is given by the variable named `orthologs`.

Surprisingly, a new collection was created with the name `annotations_keys`. It contains only one document : `{ "_id" : "UniProt", "value" : null }`.

Is it normal? If not, what is the problem?

Comment: are you sure you're putting `'annotations'` as the collection name?

Answer (score 0):

Yes Rafael, I'm sure.

The new created collection is really named 'annotationS'+'_keys' like the initial collection 'annotationS'. In addition, annotation['_id'] comes from a loop that finds in the db each document ('annotation') corresponding to the request:

```
annotation = db['annotations'].find_one({'class': 'CDS', 'locus_tag': annotated_molecule.name})
```